# Take Json in a fixture and inject only a certain value based on functionName

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have a pytest fixture that gets a json block from a database. I have a few functions that need an attribute from the json based on the serial id. This json will grow as more ids are need for other test cases. The serials id map to each method, is there a way to inject only the serial ids I need to each method?

Json example: `{["serial": 1334312, ...],["serial": 32285678, ...], ...}`

```
def my_test_1334312(fixture):
    #this will use this id from the json: 1334312
    ...

def my_test_32285678(fixture):
    ...
```

Comment: the example json doesn't appear to be valid unfortunately. also can you post desired or expected behavior? for ex. inside first test func, what is desired input/output/behavior?

Comment: I would reconsider your design. Set the data filtering on the database side. Have each test pass their serial value to the fixture so that the query can return only what you need for that test.